# push notification on/off

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, push, server-push

I integrated push notification for my android app, I want to turn on/off push notification for any android mobile/tab,Can anyone please help me...

```
protected void onPostExecute(BlogInfo result){
            if(result.IsNew && result.Blog != null){
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "THE BUTCHER BARKS", System.currentTimeMillis());
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Service.this, Bark.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GuruService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "BARKS", result.Blog.Title, pendingIntent);
                manager.notify(1, notification);
            }
        }
```

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you mean that you want to give your users an option to turn it on or off?

Comment: As per your code I think that it is not push notification it is simple notification. So how you want to start/stop the notification ?

Answer (score 2):

Save one value in the shared preference whether push message ON or OFF.

then whenever push messages are arrived to app it will call onMessage method in your GCMIntentService.then write the condition within onMessage.

```
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(preference.getPushStatus().equals("ON"))
        Log.d("onMessage",arg1.getExtras().getString("message"));   

}
```